# How to check the MIMO power save state in a WiFi Beacon frame?

Tags: ieee-802.11

I'm testing one WiFi Gateway where the toggle option for MIMO power save mode need to be tested.I'm capturing the WiFi beacon frames using sniffer but I'm not able to find out which information element represents the MIMO power save mode.

Please help